# QProcess prints output with some commands

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qprocess

I'm facing a weird problem with Qt5 and C++ on windows 10.

I have to run a QProcess and detect its output, but it prints only with some commands (actually just one):
with the `ping` command, it prints the output normally:

```
process->start("ping 8.8.8.8");
process->waitForFinished();
std::cout << process->readAllStandardOutput();
```

but with `echo` it doesn't print anything:

```
process->start("echo foo")
```

I tried changing the command (like `dir`) but it doesn't work; playing with (") or (') doesn't work either.

After some research I found that the command failed to start. Why is that?

Comment: Windows' cmd.exe is a weird animal, so that can explain the `echo` weirdness. But changing directories in a subprocess can never change the active directory of other processes

Comment: `QProcess` is made for launching programs, not wild commands. Look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#start), you'll see that you need to provide the program, and the arguments list as parameters to `QProcess::start()`. You could try `process->start("echo", {"foo"});` (but I'm not sure it will work though since it requires a console). Or maybe, `process->start("cmd.exe", {"echo", "foo"});` would be better (maybe you would need to give the full path to cmd.exe)

Comment: I know, I was just simplifying.. My final goal is to run a process to execute a command over ssh..

Comment: Additionnally, you should also read the standard error output as well, otherwise you won't be able to see what errors happened.

Comment: I tried even with std error, but nothing changed as well

Comment: `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` and `QProcess::readAllStandardError()` only give the outputs of the running process, not the one of the QProcess object itself. In other words, if your process failed to start, etc... These functions will be useless, hence why you should first take a look at `QProcess::error()` (and `QProcess::errorString()` if needed) first, to ensure that the launching occurred successfully.

Comment: You're confusing commands and programs. `ping` is an actual program (a `ping.exe` actually exists). `echo` is a command for the prompt (there is no `echo.exe`). The difference is that `ping` *actually* provides an output in std (which the prompt *also* shows), `echo` just shows the output in the prompt, but it doesn't provide an actual output, because it's not a process.

Comment: Testing the `echo` built-in command and driving `ssh.exe` are two *very* different beasts. Suggest using libssh2 instead of poking at ssh.

Comment: I know that with libssh2 it would be easier but i cannot use it.. And I hate the fact that on my linux pc works perfectly

Comment: @Ravazz That's because on linux `echo` **is** a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to run the process with:

```
cmd /c
```

So the final result is:

```
process->start("cmd /c \"echo foo\" ");
```

Comment: Slightly less heinous: `process->start("cmd", {"/c", "echo foo"});` But the documentation does warn about cmd's quoting requirements so YMMV.